# How to navigate to a screen that’s two levels down nested navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a navigation structure of three levels, the first level is in App.js

```
const AppFlow = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AppFlow.Navigator initialRouteName={'Signin'} >
                <AppFlow.Screen name='Signin' component={SigninScreen} />
                <AppFlow.Screen name='Signup' component={SignupScreen} />
                <AppFlow.Screen name='mainFlow' component={mainFlowComponent} />
            </AppFlow.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

The second is in mainFlowComponent:

```
const mainFlow = createBottomTabNavigator();

const mainFlowComponent = () => {
    return (
        <mainFlow.Navigator initialRouteName='showTrack'>
            <mainFlow.Screen name='showTrack' component={showTrackFlowComponent} />
            <mainFlow.Screen name='TrackCreate' component={TrackCreateScreen} />
            <mainFlow.Screen name='Account' component={AccountScreen} />
        </mainFlow.Navigator>
    );
};
```

And the third in showTrackComponent:

```
const showTrackFlow = createStackNavigator();

const showTrackFlowComponent = () => {
    return (
        <showTrackFlow.Navigator initialRouteName={'TrackList'} >
            <showTrackFlow.Screen name='TrackList' component={TrackListScreen} />
            <showTrackFlow.Screen name='TrackDetail' component={TrackDetailScreen} />
        </showTrackFlow.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Now, I need to navigate from SigninScreen that’s in the first navigator to TrackList that’s in the third navigator (two levels down)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/ only shows how to navigate just 1 level down

I’m doing

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('showTrack', { screen: 'TrackList'});
```

From Signin (or Signup) screen, and I get this error

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"showTrack","params":{"screen":"TrackList"}} was not handled by any navigator
```

If I navigated to, say, TrackCreate, that’s in the second level, no error is thrown

What do I have to do?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: You need to gain access to showTrackFlowComponent's navigation object, theres a ref property on showTrackFlow.Navigator that will give you access to it and an onReady event so you know when it's available, once you have the navigation ref you could set it globally via something like window.showTrackFlowNavigation and then use it in the sign in screen

Comment: There might be a race condition wherein by the time you need showTrackFlowComponent's navigation object it might not be ready so it might take some trial and error

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Maybe using usEffect I could gain access to its value...

Comment: Hi @bryanstevens314, I think that these complications suggest that having three levels of navigation isn't a good approach, so I reduced it to two levels of navigation.

Comment: Agreed, in concept 3 levels of navigation would be really useful but the devil is always in the details